# How to concatenate values of multiple parameters for a list of objects?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, collections

I have JSON object like that

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "FName":"Islam",
         "LName":"Mohamed",
         "Id": 1
      },
      {
         "FName":"Ali",
         "LName":"Amr",
         "Id": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to concatenate all FName and LName for each object to get String like that

```
val result: String = "Islam,Mohamed,Ali,Amr"
```

What is the best way to do that using collection functions in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 1):

There is [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) function

`val result = users.joinToString(",") { "${it.fName},${it.lName}" }`